# Can't access Knockout viewmodel methods from any context

Tags: knockout.js

I have a nested view model which has some methods I can't access, either from the current context or the parent context.

A simplified version of the viewmodel, which shows the same problems is:

```
ModelB = function () {
    var self=this;

    self.listItems = ko.observableArray(['one','two']);

    self.clickMe = function () {
        alert('clicked');
    };

};

ModelA = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.modelBList = new ModelB();
};  

ko.applyBindings(new ModelA());
```

used together with the view

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: modelBList.listItems">
    <li data-bind="text: $data, click: $parent.clickMe"></li>
</ul>
```

doesn't work when I click one of the `<li>` elements, nothing happens.

Using developer tools, I've found that within the `<li>` elements `$parent` is resolving to the root context, which is ModelA, not ModelB as I had expected.

How can I access methods within ModelB?

Comment: In the click binding `$parent` is `ModelA`.  You need to navigate into the `modelBList`property:   `click:  $parent.modelBList.clickMe`

Comment: you refereed `listItems` using modelBList extension, similarly do for `clickMe` .reason why you use $parent is `foreach` hides outer scope. with no foreach http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/47911/

Answer (score 0):

Knockout binding contexts do not necessarily reflect the structure of your view-model. They are created based on the html markup

> [each time you use a control flow binding such as "with" or "foreach", that creates a child binding context that refers to the nested view model data.](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

In your view model the hierarchy is ModelA -> ModelB, but in the markup there's $root which is ModelA, and then the next context that is created is for the listItems array so its parent is directly mapped up to the root (ModelA), entirely skipping ModelB. Binding to "ModelB.listItems" doesn't create a context for each part of the path it just tells it the final target to bind to.

If you want to create an intermediate context for ModelB you could first use the "with" binding, either with a div or a container-less binding:

```
<!--ko with: modelBList-->
<ul data-bind="foreach: listItems">
    <li data-bind="text: $data, click: $parent.clickMe"></li>
</ul>
<!--/ko-->
```

Or as Jose Luis said you can navigate from the existing context using

```
<li data-bind="text: $data, click: $parent.modelBList.clickMe"></li>
```